# How can I split an exchange that contains a list of files in apache camel and write each file on the filesystem

Tags: java, apache-camel

As the question says I'm trying to write a bunch of files (3 in this case) to the filesystem after aggregating them and then splitting them.

How can I do this in camel? I'm using 2.16.5 as this is the camel version of the project I'm woking on.

This is the code that to my mind is supposed to do this:

```
// reads 
public class StringRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:readStrings")
            .split(body())
            .to("file:input?fileExist=Append&fileName=${body}.txt"); 
    // appending each message to diff file
}


import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

import org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy;

public class AggregatorRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:input")
            .aggregate(new GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy())
            .constant(true)
            .completionSize(3)
            .to("direct:splitFiles");

        from("direct:splitFiles")
            .split(body())
            .to("direct:writeFiles");
    }
}

public class FileWriter extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:writeFiles")
            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("In FileWriter: " + exchange.getIn().getBody());
                }
            })
            .to("file:output?fileName=${body}.txt");
    }
}

    // Main
import routes.AggregatorRoute;
import routes.FileWriter;
import routes.StringRoute;
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
    try {
        camelContext.addRoutes(new StringRoute());
        camelContext.start();
        ProducerTemplate producerTemplate = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String a = "abc";
        String b = "cdb";
        String c = "efg";
        list.add(a); list.add(b); list.add(c);
        producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:readStrings", list);
        camelContext.addRoutes(new AggregatorRoute());
        camelContext.addRoutes(new FileWriter());
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        camelContext.stop();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As you can see there are no files in output directory.

[result.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YDNa.png)

Comment: Have you got any error log message? Can you tell us how far your code works and where the data is stuck or lost?

Comment: The error log is in result.png. No errors occur. The problem is that no files are present in output directory (look in the attached picture).

Comment: Yeah, but the output directory is the final output after 3 routes. What about input directory? Are the files written there? Are they consumed again by the aggregator? Does the aggregator create an output message? You just say "there is no output, it is not working". Do some research to find out how far it is working and where it stops working and then write these facts in your question. Otherwise it is like looking for the needle in the haystack.

Comment: @burki my dear, look at main. I create a list of strings. Use producer template to send that list to StringRoute. From there it writes 3 files to input -> aggregates -> splits -> problem in FileWriter (it should write to output)

Comment: Main says what it should do, but not what actually works. So you say that everything works, you see the output `"In FileWriter: " + exchange.getIn().getBody()` for the aggregated file, but it does not write the file to `output`?

Comment: You are trying set `GenericFile` object as fileName, this is not what you want. Also `to` cannot work with dynamic expressions. Maybe you want something like this `.toD("file:output?fileName=${body.fileName}")`

Comment: @burki, yes you got it now

Comment: @Bedla I wanted to use ?fileName=${header.CamelFileName} but I was too lazy to to actually research how to send the headers so I just ended up using the content of the files as the file names. From my knowledge ${body} just gets the content of a file, so ${body.fileName} looks a little fishy to me

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the picture until now, the domain seems to be blocked where I was. Try to set a String as `fileName`, currently it is an `Exchange` object (the body). The OS is probably not very happy with the name `Exchange[][Message: ...].txt`.

Comment: And either use the AggregationStrategy that Rajkumar suggested or, if you need the Exchange object, overwrite the body with only the In-Message before you write it to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be got the exception **No consumers available on endpoint: Endpoint[direct://splitFiles]** because definition of direct:splitFiles was actually below it was accessed in the **file:input**.

So I moved the definition as a first step.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregationStrategy;

public class AggregatorRoute extends RouteBuilder {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("direct:splitFiles")
                .split(body())
                .convertBodyTo(String.class)
                .to("direct:writeFiles")
            ;

            from("file:input")
                .convertBodyTo(String.class)
                .log("current message:: ${body}")
                .aggregate(new AggregationStrategy() {
                    @Override
                    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
                        String newMessage=newExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                        List<String> messageList=null;
                        if(oldExchange == null) {
                            messageList=new ArrayList<String>();
                        }
                        if(oldExchange != null && newExchange!=null) {
                            messageList=oldExchange.getIn().getBody(List.class);
                        }
                        messageList.add(newMessage);
                        newExchange.getOut().setBody(messageList);
                        return newExchange;
                    }

                })
                .constant(true)
                .completionSize(3)
                .log("current message:: ${body}")
                .to("direct:splitFiles")
           ;

        }
    }
```

you should use **GroupedMessageAggregationStrategy** instead of **GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy** if you just want to aggregate the message.

Finally in Main.java also flipped the order to get rid of the **No consumers Exception for direct:writeFiles**

```
camelContext.addRoutes(new FileWriter());    
camelContext.addRoutes(new AggregatorRoute());
```

Comment: No, I am not getting that exception. I am getting no exceptions. The only problem I have is that the files are not being written in the output folder.

Comment: Then Change your AggregationStrategy as GroupedMessageAggregationStrategy.  I modified your program and able to see three files in Output folder.

Comment: Indeed it works if I change the aggregation strategy, but only if I also add .convertBody(String.class) before the aggregation occurs. Any ideeas why? Also why doesn't the old aggregation strategy work?  BTW I mentioned I'm using camel 2.16.5 and for MessageAggregation you need newer version.

Comment: Sorry I was using the latest Camel and tried your program on top of that.
The reason its not working for GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy  is because it will have the aggregated array of Exchange information. You have to have a code to extract the data from the Exchange array before the actual split.
Since GroupedMessageAggregationStrategy is not part of 2.16.5 you can implement your own AggregationStrategy.

Comment: Updated the answer with custom AggregationStrategy

Comment: The actual solution posted by Raj didn't actually fix my problem, but it put me on the right path to finding the solution. The end result is quite a bit more complicated than what is presented here, but I will give Rajkumar the correct solution for this problem. Thanks a lot